# Simple DropDownList Filter?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

This is a topic that seems to be constantly brought up, but other posts seemed to be overly complex for what I would like to do.. Below is the dropdownlist I am creating in the Index view. All I want is to use this dropdown as a way to change the filter on my view.

**Index**

`@Html.DropDownList("PageFilter", ViewData["pgFilter"] as List<SelectListItem>)`

**Controller**

```
       List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
       li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Status & Test", Value = "0" });
       li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Status", Value = "1" });
       li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Test", Value = "2" });
       li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No Filter", Value = "3" });
       ViewData["pgFilter"] = li;
```

The idea is pretty basic. If the first item is selected, both the 'Status' field and the 'Test' field are filtered using a specific filter. They could also choose to only select one filter or no filter.

However, I have been struggling to find a simple solution to pass the selected item to the controller to run If statements on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method if you are not using any models.

Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
           public ActionResult MyDropDownView()
        {
            // shows your form when you load the page
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Status & Test", Value = "0" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Status", Value = "1" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Test", Value = "2" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "No Filter", Value = "3" });
            ViewData["pgFilter"] = li;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyResultAction(string selectedFilterId)
        {
            //do what ever you want
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyResultAction", "Home"))
        {

            @Html.DropDownList("selectedFilterId", ViewData["pgFilter"] as List<SelectListItem>, "--pick--", new
{
    title = "Pick Filter",
    onchange = "submit();"
});

        }
```

Sleeted item value will be passed to the `Home` controller's `MyResultAction`

Hope this helps.